# Find and Replace Multiple occurrences of a string within a large string

Tags: string, powershell, replace, substring

I have a large string.

I want to find a specific tag from the large string and replace content within that tag. This tag could occur multiple times and has to be replaced each time.

Below is my code:

```
$FirstString = '<tag>'
$lastString  = '</tag>'

$contentVal = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. <tag> Aha Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</tag>, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, <tag> Aha imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.</tag> Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. <tag> Aha Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.</tag>"

if ($contentVal.Contains('<tag>')) {
    $Pos1 = $contentVal.IndexOf($FirstString) + $FirstString.Length;
    $Pos2 = $contentVal.IndexOf($lastString);

    #Find text between <tag> and </tag> 
    $FoundString = $contentVal.Substring($Pos1, $Pos2 - $Pos1);
    Write-Host $FoundString

    #Modify this FoundString by finding Aha and replacing with <br/>
    $FinalString = $FinalString.Replace("Aha","</br>")
    Write-Host $FinalString
}
```

Now I want to append this `$finalString` to `$contentVal` at the same position at which it was earlier.

Also, I have multiple occurences of `<tag>`.

How to manipulate each occurence and append to main string?

Comment: Is your string proper XML/HTML, or do you have tags arbitrarily inside an otherwise regular string?

Comment: Is `$FinalString = $FinalString.Replace()` a typo in your question or in your actual code?

Comment: Its a proper html and contains mark up and tags. $FinalString.Replace("Aha","</br>") This is to find some text "Aha" in the $FoundString and replace it with </br>

Comment: Then use a proper XML/HTML parser instead of parsing the file yourself. `[xml]$html = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.html'`

Comment: The tags within the content are not xml tags.

Comment: HTML is an XML dialect. Please actually try what I suggested before you start arguing.